# How do I break large words in a string using Groovy regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I'd like to break up large words (say 10 characters or more) found in a string into multiple lines.  For example I'd like to convert

> I will not stand for this antidisestablishmentarianism!

to

> I will not stand for this antidisest
>   ablishment
>   arianism!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String str = "I will not stand for this antidisestablishmentarianism!"

def newStr = (str =~ /(\w{10})/).replaceAll("\$1\n")

println newStr
```

The 10 determines the length of words to be split up

Comment: The string can also be splitted using [`String#replaceAll(Pattern, String)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String%29), like `str.replaceAll(/(\w{10})/, "\$1\n")`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nik's answer, you may be interested in alternative solutions.

I don't know what is your exact task, but sometimes hyphenation can be more natural.

---

Check out [Hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), Javascript library for client-side hyphenation.

> Usage example: http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%204.0.0/WorkingExample.html

---

Also check out Hyphenation CSS3 properties: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#hyphenation

---

Also consider CSS3 [`overflow-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap0) property, that forces words to break in the middle if there is no choice:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Legacy alternative name for `overflow-wrap`:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

> Usage example: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/word-wrap/

Comment: Thanks to Nik and everyone else.  Praises sung over at http://code.christophervigliotti.com/2012/01/how-nik-broke-up-large-words-found-in-a-string-using-regex/